# How many armor stand can minecraft support?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map with noLAG proven, but I need to know how many armor stands can exist in a world to avoid the lag from them?

Comment: I don't believe there's any hard limit (not one that you'll encounter, at least). The lag will gradually increase as you add more stands.

Comment: This is extremely broad. It depends not only on the users computer, but also on what the armorstand actually does. For example, I get around 10-20 fps when I summon in 1000 armorstands. If they are invisible, I get 70 fps, when executing a simple command at 1000 invisible armorstands, it drops to 40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how fast your computer is. Some computers even get lag with no Armor Stands in the world. I suggest not having too much though. Read [this article](https://www.bisecthosting.com/clients/knowledgebase/76/How-to-troubleshoot-and-reduce-lag.html) if you want to reduce lag on your map.